# Как работает RedirectToAction()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты

Сначала я думал, что `RedirectToAction(`) срабатывает сразу и как бы просто вызывается другой метод. Но стало казаться, что `RedirectToAction()` сначала отправляет запрос клиенту, чтобы тот перешел на такой-то метод с таким-то контроллером.
Вся суть в юнит тесте:

```
ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
Assert.AreEqual("Main", result.ViewName);
```

Кстати метод `Index` возвращает `ActionResult`, в примерах я видел, что as `ViewResult` должен `ActionResult` привести к `ViewResult`. Но в самом методе происходит `RedirectToAction("Main")` в котором возвращается представление `Main`. В таком случае в `result` остается `null`.
Но можно и так:

```
ActionResult result = controller.Index();
```

Хотя в таком случае никакую полезную информацию из `result` я достать не смогу.

Comment: И если `RedirectToAction()` сначала отправляет запрос клиенту, то как в тесте поймать просьбу на переадресацию, чтобы затем в тесте вызвать соответствующий контроллер(можно конечно просто создать его конструктором, но в таком случае я буду предполагать, что переадресация точно сработает, что не есть хорошо)

Answer (score 3):

> Но стало казаться, что RedirectToAction() сначала отправляет запрос клиенту, чтобы тот перешел на такой-то метод с таким-то контроллером.

Вам не просто кажется, это так и есть на самом деле. Слово "redirect" в web-разработке испокон веков означало ответ клиенту с кодом из диапазона 300-399, получив который браузер должен перейти по адресу указанному в заголовке Location.

---

Что же до тестов - тут все просто. **Во-первых**, если вы знаете что метод должен вернуть ViewResult - ничто не мешает сделать приведение типа:

```
var result = (ViewResult)controller.Index();
```

Отмечу, что в тестах предпочтительнее использовать именно такую форму приведения типа вместо `as`. Операция `as` нужна если события могут пойти по-разному, метод может вернуть ViewResult а может и не вернуть его. Но тест на то и тест что вы должны заранее знать что метод возвращает, и приведение типа через скобки работает одновременно как проверка.

**Во-вторых**, помните: ActionResult - это лишь пожелание со стороны контроллера, а еще не действие! Ни один наследник ActionResult не начинает исполняться просто из-за того что его вернул вам контроллер из своего метода.

Когда приходит запрос от браузера - ASP.NET сначала вызывает метод контроллера, потом отдельно исполняет ActionResult (вызывает его метод ExecuteResult). Но если вы в своем тесте не вызовете ExecuteResult - то и исполняться он не будет.

Кстати, RedirectToAction возвращает RedirectToRouteResult.

**В-третьих**, не нужно пытаться протестировать в одном тесте сразу несколько контроллеров. Вы убедились что Index редиректит на Main - ок, эта проверка пройдена. Проверять метод Main нужно в другом тесте.

Answer (score 0):

Я подумал что лучше было бы сделать так:

```
 ActionResult result = controller.Authorization(model);
 if((result as ViewResult) == null)
 {
     string action = (result as RedirectToRouteResult).RouteValues["action"] as string;
     string controller= (result as RedirectToRouteResult).RouteValues["controller"] as string;
 }
```

в таком случае в action и controller будет информация по переадресации